# Root system of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ and reduction to $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ root system

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems

I know that the root system of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$ can be described as the vector space spanned by $\{a^1, a^2, \ldots, a^{n-1}\}$ with inner product given by the Killing form,

$$(a^i,a^j)= 2\delta_{i,j} - \delta_{i+1,j}-\delta_{i,j+1}.$$

However, I have trouble understanding how it relates to the root system of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ which is of higher rank? What is a basis and the Killing form for the general linear lie algebra?

Secondly, if I start with a root lattice of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$ how does it reduce to the root lattice of $\mathfrak{sl}_n$?

Comment: See [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/135567/computation-of-the-killing-form-of-mathfrakgl-m?rq=1) for the Killing form.

Comment: Recently discussed this in the comments to https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3759751/96384. What is your definition of "the root system of $\mathfrak{gl}_n$" though?

Comment: Maybe this answer is helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1448506/mathfrakgl-style-vs-mathfraksl-style-fundamental-weights-for-a-r/1449784#1449784l.